# Plot a function with parameters that don't have numerical values

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a plot such as the one in the picture below:

[image]

Note that there no ticks on the y-axis and the x-axis ticks are expressed in term of a parameter -- the function being presented as if it were evaluated only qualitatively and the plot can be considered to be of a function describing a general phenomenon.

I tried with

```
F[t_] = Imax (1 - Exp[-t/tau])
Plot[F[t], {t, 0, 3 tau}]
```

but obviously that was not the correct way to do it. Is it possible to do such a thing with Mathematica?

Comment: The last two examples in the Scope > Ticks Positions and Labeling section of the docs, http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html, shows how to do it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour] so you learn the basic rules of the site. Once you gain enough reputation by making [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) you will be able to vote up and down both questions and answers. [Your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but its a good idea to wait 24hours for other answers before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. (Notice the links to useful information)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For plots like this you're plotting in units of Imax, and tau so replace t/tau with t'=t/tau then t'=1 when t=tau etc. You can use ticks to indicate this. `Imax` is just a scaling parameter, so leave it as 1 and everything is relative to `Imax`:

```
Plot[
 {Callout[(1 - Exp[-t]), "I(t)"], Callout[t, "τ=L/R"], 
  Callout[1, "Im=f/R"]}
 ,
 {t, 0, 4},
 Ticks -> {
   {#, ToString@# <> "τ"} & /@ Range[3],
   None}
 , AxesLabel -> {"t", "I"}
 , PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}
 , PlotStyle -> {Black, Directive[Black, Dashed], 
   Directive[Black, Dashed]}
 ]
```

[image]

The `Callouts` are a little wonky in this example, but they are the simplest way to label curves like this.

Comment: For those who are picky, the following give the labels & ticks displayed the way they're suppose to display in `TraditionalForm`: ``Ticks -> {{#, # * HoldForm[\[Tau]]} & /@ Range[3], None}`` and  ``AxesLabel -> {Automatic, DisplayForm@RowBox[{"I"}]}``.  (If you're really picky, use MaTeX.)

Comment: Your solution was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

You must use a numerical value for plotting, but you can easily label your axes with whatever you want in this form:

```
Ticks-> {{{1, "τ"},{2, "2τ"},{3, "3τ"}}, Automatic}
```

Incidentally, what is the value of `Imax`?

```
Plot[{1, x Cos[5 π/16], Exp[-1/x]}, 
{x, 0, 3}, 
PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Automatic, Automatic}, 
Ticks -> {{{1, "τ"}, {2, "2τ"}, {3, "3τ"}}, None}, 
Epilog -> {Text @@@ 
          {{"t = L/R", {0.5, 1.3}}, 
           {"I(t)", {1.4, 0.3}}, 
           {"Im = f/R", {2.5, 1.1}}}, 
           Arrow /@ 
          {{{0.5, 1.3}, {0.2, 1}}, 
          {{1.4, 0.3}, {1.2, 0.4}}}}]
```

Comment: Thanks anyway. Are you 100% sure there is no way to get a generic plot, but labelling after the plot is done?
By the way, `Imax` It's just the asymptotic value that the function approaches as t goes to infinity!

Comment: It's the trend of the current in a `LR` circuit with constant voltage

Comment: Absolutely positive there's no way to get a plot with a generic (unspecified) variable.  After all, how could the software know where to plot a point?  You can, of course, define your variables beforehand (e.g., `tau = 1;`) and then apply your `Plot` referring to these values, but *generically*, absolutely not.  Imagine plotting $1/(x - q)$ versus $x$ and not knowing the numerical value of $q$ (whether it was positive or negative or zero)!!

Answer (score 1):

You can create each graphic instance and show them together. Though, as far as I know, you must provide numerical values. Then its a matter of tweaking values to get the graphics you want.

```
p1 = Plot[1, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
  Ticks -> {{{1, "τ"}, {2, "2τ"}, {3, "3τ"}}, 
    Automatic}] (*only one plot needs the ticks*)
p2 = Plot[x*Cos[5 Pi/16], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
p3 = Plot[1/Exp[1/x], {x, 0, 3}]
t1 = Graphics[Text["t = L/R", {0.5, 1.3}]]
t2 = Graphics[Text["I(t)", {1.4, 0.3}]]
t3 = Graphics[Text["Im = f/R", {2.5, 1.1}]]
a1 = Graphics[Arrow[{{0.5, 1.3}, {0.2, 1}}]]
a2 = Graphics[Arrow[{{1.4, 0.3}, {1.2, 0.4}}]]
Show[p1, p2, p3, t1, t2, t3, a1, a2]
```

[image: output]

Comment: Far simpler:  `Plot[
 {1, x Cos[5 Pi/16], 1/Exp[1/x]}, {x, 0, 3},
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Automatic, Automatic}, 
 Ticks -> {{{1, "\[Tau]"}, {2, "2\[Tau]"}, {3, "3\[Tau]"}}, None},
 Epilog -> {Text @@@ {{"t = L/R", {0.5, 1.3}}, {"I(t)", {1.4, 
       0.3}}, {"Im = f/R", {2.5, 1.1}}}, 
   Arrow /@ {{{0.5, 1.3}, {0.2, 1}}, {{1.4, 0.3}, {1.2, 0.4}}}}]`

Comment: @Pedro H. N. Vieira Você acha que o `http://www.texample.net/tikz/` poderia ajudar?